# How Can use real-time workflow in CRM 2015?

Tags: workflow, real-time, crm

I have a real-time workflow for creating unique numbers. This workflow get a numeric field from my custom entity, increase it by 1, and update it for next use.
I want to run this workflow on multiple records.
Running on-demand mode, it works fine,and I have true and unique numbers, but for "Record is Created" mode, it dose not work fine and get repeated numbers.
What I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

This approach wont work, when the workflow runs on demand its running multi-threaded, e.g. two users create two records, two instances of the workflow start. As there is no locking mechanism you end up with duplicated numbers.

I'm guessing this isn't happening when running on demand because you are running as a single user.

You will need to implement a custom auto number approach, such as [Auto Number for DynamicsCRM](http://www.gapconsulting.co.uk/our-solutions/essentials/auto-number-for-dynamicscrm).

> Disclaimer: I work for Gap Consulting who produce the tool linked above.

Comment: Thanks. I have read the following link and do steps It works:https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/auto-number-generation-using-real-time-workflow-in-ms-crm-2013/

Comment: Yeah doesn't look like it will work, comments on the article are complaining about duplicates as well.